# Android: Find destination location given distance and bearing

Tags: android, dictionary, location

For my Android App, I am looking for Google's API to get destination/end location provided distance and bearing. I tried the following 2 methods:
1. Using SphericalUtil:

```
SphericalUtil.computeOffsetOrigin(startLocation, distance, bearing);
```

2. Using OsmDroid:

   ```
   GeoPoint startLocation = ...;

   startLocation.destinationPoint(distance, bearing);
   ```

They work for smaller distances but for distances greater than a few kilometers, they differ significantly from Google Earth's values. I believe this is due to the different Earth Radius they take in consideration, as the radius is inconsistent throughout the globe.

So, is there a Google Map's API that gets destination location? I believe it'll be consistent with Google Earth application.